# Unable to execute copy commands in cmd.exe using QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Having issue using Qprocess to execute the copy command
below are my codes:

```
QProcess* m_pCopyDirContent = new QProcess(this);

QString m_sourceDir = "C:\A\*.*";
QString m_destDir = "C:\B\*.*";
QString m_Overwrite = "/Y";
m_pCopyDirContent->start(QString("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\cmd.exe /C copy %1 
%2 %3").arg(m_sourceDir).arg(m_destDir).arg(m_Overwrite));
```

nothing happens after executing the above code.

I tested out a simple code like:

```
Process->start("cmd.exe /C start C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/test.txt")
```

and it does work but not mine.

Comment: What if you try to use slashes in your paths: `"C:/A/*.*"?

Comment: OK it works!!! thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QString m_sourceDir = "C:\A\*.*";
```

should be

```
QString m_sourceDir = "C:\\A\\*.*";
```

etc.

In fact your compiler should have given you warnings about illegal escape sequences.